# AM $\geq$ GM anomaly

Tags: sequences-and-series

We all know, that $AM\ge GM$, here is a problem I faced, while solving a problem-

Let there be $2$ numbers $a$ and $b$, such that $ab\le 0$

**Case 1**
$$
\frac{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}}{2}\ge\sqrt{1}
$$$$
\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab}\ge2
$$

**Case 2**
$$
\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\ge\sqrt{a^2b^2}
$$$$
\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\ge ab
$$
Since $ab$ is negative, and we are transposing it to the left, we invert the inequality-
$$
\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab}\le2
$$
The result here contradicts the result obtained in case 1. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't typeset it faithfully. It was a mistake.

Comment: AM/GM isn't true for negative values. Indeed, the square root of $ab$ is imaginary, so can't be compared with a real number.

Comment: In particular, the first inequality is obviously false, since $\frac ab$ and $\frac ba$ are both negative, so the LHS is negative, so it cannot be greater than a positive value.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by "$AP\geq GP$?" Usually, it is written "AM\geq GM" where "M" denotes "mean." AP and GP usually refer to "progressions" for sequences: $1,3,5,7,\dots$ being an arithmetic progression and $1,2,4,8,\dots$ being a geometric progression.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry for that, I know, just skipped my mind.

Answer (score 2):

AM/GM is not valid for negative numbers.

In particular, it is not true that $\dfrac{\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}}2 \geq \sqrt{1}$ when $ab<0$, since then the left side is negative and $\sqrt{1}>0$.

Answer (score 1):

since $ab<0$ we get
$a<0$ and $b>0$ or $a<0$ and $b>0$ then we get $$a/b+b/a<0$$ and case 1) can not be
for case 2) we obtain $$\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\geq \sqrt{a^2b^2}=|ab|>0$$